# "app keeps stopping" error android studio

Tags: android-studio, class, kotlin, global-variables

I'm writing in kotlin and i'm creating an application which should roll two dices. Since i have created a function named randomize i have to create a global variable for "textView" (and textView2).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
var textView2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    textView2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    textView.text = randomize()
    textView2.text = randomize()

    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener{
        textView.text = randomize()
        textView2.text = randomize()
    }

    val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    button2.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?q=${textView.text.toString()}+${textView2.text.toString()}"))
        startActivity(intent)
    }


}



private fun randomize() : String{
    return floor((Math.random()*6)+1).toInt().toString()
}
```

If i run the emulator i got an error "app keeps stopping" and if i look to the debugger i see that the error is in the global initialization of textView and textView2 (third and fourth line of the code shown above).

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is

```
textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.**textView**)
textView2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.**textView**)
```

For both of the textview you have called the same id I guess that's why there's an issue check your XML file and issue the correct id

Comment: I changed the code as you said but is still not working and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Actually why are mentioning your textview 2 times? you have already called it before oncreate function so try removing the one which is inside oncreate you don't have to call the textview with id two times

Comment: still not working. From the debugger i see the same error at the same line.

Comment: So as you have made changes can you edit with that new code?